# Shiny dashboard rpivotTable layout

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rpivottable

I have a pivottable generated from rpivotTable library.I am using shiny dashboard to show the output of the pivottable in a box. The fit doesn't seem to be right.

Below is the screenshot of how the output looks like.

[image]

I tried to get the box size to match the pivottable size and have a scroll bar if the size of the pivottable is more. But the background color, "skin-blue", doesn't seem to be fitting according to the size of the box.

below is a sample code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rpivotTable)
header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("Menu1",icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("Sub1", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub2", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub3", icon = icon("dashboard"))
           ),
  menuItem("Menu2",icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("Sub12", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub22", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub32", icon = icon("dashboard"))))
body <- dashboardBody(

  tabItem(tab = "sub1",

          box(width = 12,selectInput("testip",label = "Input",choices = c("A","B","C")),
              selectInput("testip1",label = "Input",choices = c("A","B","C")),
              selectInput("testip2",label = "Input",choices = c("A","B","C")),
                            actionButton("submit","Submit")),
          box(width = 12,height = "800px",
            tags$head(tags$style( type = 'text/css',  '#myPivot{ overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; }')),
            rpivotTableOutput("myPivot", height = "780px")))

)
dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$myPivot <- renderRpivotTable(rpivotTable(data = mtcars, rows = "mpg", cols = "disp"))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing heights at ui

```
tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css',  '#Alert{ overflow-x: scroll; }')),
rpivotTableOutput("myPivot"))
```

Then at server, define heights

```
output$myPivot <- renderRpivotTable(rpivotTable(data = mtcars, rows = "mpg", cols = "disp", height = "780px"))
```

This works for me.